# Very very slow NFS performance

Tags: centos, nfs, ubuntu-10.10

I'm having a quite strange issue. I'm mounting a NFS share from a SAN (ubuntu) to another machine (centos)

Mounting the share works just fine; but when I try some tests like :

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=bigfile bs=1k count=2000
2000+0 records in
2000+0 records out
2048000 bytes (2.0 MB) copied, 16.7555 seconds, 122 kB/s
```

On clientside, network has MTU 9000; i can successfully ping -s 8000 at least the server.

On SAN side it has 4 Gigabit interfaces bonded.

Both sides run NFS4; mounting using :

```
mount -t nfs4 192.168.3.3:/share /myshare/
```

Where should I start investigating ?

And what is the average transfer rate I could accept ? 50 Mb/s for a single gigabit connection ?

edit:
server exports :

```
/export/share *(rw,insecure,async,no_subtree_check)
```

edit:
local storage test

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=bigfile2 bs=1k count=200000
200000+0 records in
200000+0 records out
204800000 bytes (205 MB) copied, 0.509998 seconds, 402 MB/s

real    0m0.558s
user    0m0.009s
sys 0m0.546s
```

Comment: What if you repeat the test locally on the server? This way you can verify if it is NFS issue. What if you try larger file? What if you `rsync/scp` over SSH and test? What are your server export and client mount options?

Comment: edited question with local test. I'll tryp scp and report.

Comment: ok scp gives an average of 52 mb/s; but it's with the encryption overhead i think, no ? should it be faster ?

Comment: Could you please show the client mount options?

Comment: FWIW I've heard rumors NFS 3 is faster than 4...

Answer (score 6):

You could try using different mount options than the defaults. Might be worth trying the following using the `mount -o` option and rerunning your `dd` test.

`rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,timeo=600,actime=0`

Try reading `man nfs` for details on the mount options and what they mean.

Comment: mount -t nfs4 -o rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=32768, wsize=32768,tcp,timeo=600,actime=0 doesn't seem to work.

Comment: 10 years later, I found this useful, thanks for sharing. For future readers, make sure to remove the spaces in this answer. In other words, run `sudo mount -t nfs4 -o rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,timeo=600,actime=0 host:/my/shared/dir /my/mount/dir`

Comment: Um actime option has been removed.. Likewise nointr option is deprecated.. so it's on its way out.. other than that, it's a great command.. thank you..